# Как сделать условие короче PHP

Tags: php

Есть код, который обрезает строку от : до ; если это необходимо

```
$res = $value['name'];
                    
if (strlen($res) <= 128) {
    $results = $res;
} else {    
    if (strripos($res, ":") === false) {        
        if (strripos($res, ";") === false) {
            $results=mb_strimwidth($res, 0, 128);
        } else {
            $str=strpos($res, ";");
            $row=substr($res, 0, $str);
            $results=mb_strimwidth($res, 0, 128);
        }    

    } else {        
        if (strripos($res, ";") === false) {
            $row = substr(strstr($res, ':'), 1, strlen($res));
            $results=mb_strimwidth($row, 1, 128);
        } else {
            $row = substr(strstr($res, ':'), 1, strlen($res));
            $str=strpos($row, ";");
            $res=substr($row, 0, $str);
            $results=mb_strimwidth($res, 1, 128);
        }
    }
}

$item['name'] = $results;
```

Как сделать код короче? Смотрел в сторону тернарного оператора, но уж больно много костылей я нагородил

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd7d2f644f0b06c268e435f59611082dcb39a042

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А почему `.*?`, а не `.+`?

Comment: @Akina я не силён в регулярках. Но ЕМНИП, `.+` захватит все символы до конца

Comment: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b4UC

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот теперь вообще не понял. *ЕМНИП, `.+` захватит все символы до конца* - так у тебя ж потом ещё и точка с запятой, если захватить всё, то её-то не будет... У тебя другая проблема - если есть два фрагмента, они прихватятся как один. Надо `:[^;]+;`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://3v4l.org/R6sJb

Comment: что за входной текст-то ?

Comment: @Akina я исхожу из того что ТС строка с одним вхождением. Потому что судя по коду - цикл отсутствует, значит ожидание только лишь одного вхождения

Comment: входной текст например такой СКИДКА 30% НАБОР Чай "Раскрой мне, природа, объятия" + тв.мёд "Горное разнотравье": Для крепкого здоровья ароматный трав.чай "Раскрой мне, природа, объятия", 40г (20 шт*2г), KS Твердый мёд "Горное разнотравье", 30г, 1/160, 1шт.